# Cheerio extract series of articles

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I need to extract date and full URL for articles.

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
const resolveRelative = require('resolve-relative-url');
        request('https://www.moneyweb.co.za/', function (error, response, html) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                const $ = cheerio.load(html);
                $('.border0010-dotted').each(function (i, element) {
                    const title = $(this).find('.title').text().trim()
                    const url = resolveRelative($(this).find('.a href').text().trim(), response.request.uri.href)
                    const date = $(this).attr('.inline-block')
                    const description = $(this).find('.excerpt').text().trim()
                    const feedItem = {
                        title: title,
                        description: description,
                        url: url,
                        date: date
                    }
                    console.log(feedItem)
                })
            }
    });
```

Output looks like this:

```
{ title: 'Hiring a new bank CEO rarely improves the share price',
  description: 'New CEOs have done little to boost Europe bank stocks.',
  url: 'https://www.moneyweb.co.za/',
  date: undefined }
```

How can I get the date and full URL?

Comment: What issue do you have with the code provided?

Comment: hi @WaiHaLee

edited original post to show output

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing the html

Comment: @pguardiario html source is https://www.moneyweb.co.za/

Answer (score 0):

A few issues:

- `const date = $(this).attr('.inline-block')` should be `find()` rather than `attr()`. Some containers have alterate date locations, but `$(this).find(".meta .inline-block:last").prev().text();` seems to be able to get them all.
- `.border0010-dotted` appears at the bottom of the article with less data, so I'd suggest `#home-panel-loop .border0010-dotted` to refine the selector to the main content.
- The URL can be extracted from the `.title a` element by accessing its `href` attribute. `.a href` looks for a `<href>` tag inside a `class="a"` element.

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12
const request = require("request");

request("https://www.moneyweb.co.za/", function (error, response, html) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $("#home-panel-loop .border0010-dotted").each(function () {
      const title = $(this).find(".title").text().trim();
      const url = $(this).find(".title a").attr("href");
      const date = $(this)
        .find(".meta .inline-block:last")
        .prev()
        .text()
        .trim();
      const description = $(this).find(".excerpt").text().trim();
      const feedItem = {title, description, url, date};
      console.log(feedItem);
    });
  }
});
```